# Creating independent exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X,Y,U$ are three independent RVs. $X$ and $Y$ are both Exponential with an identical parameter $\lambda$, and $U$ is Uniform on $[0,1]$.

I need to plot the empirical probability of $P(X\le U\le Y)$, but I am stuck since I don't know how to create $X$ and $Y$ so they will be independent.

my MATLAB code is as follow:

```
%create unifrom vector U belongs to [0,1] containing 1e6 samples.
u = rand(1e6,1);

%create function g(u,lambda) for the RV transformation, X=g(u).
% this g(u) definition garanteed X to be with exponent PDF
g=@(u,lambda) (1./lambda).* log(1./(1-u));

lambdaVEC=0.1:0.1:3;
P_empirical=zeros(1,length(lambdaVEC));
for i=1:length(lambdaVEC)
 Currlambda=lambdaVEC(i);

    x=g(u,Currlambda);
    y=g(u,Currlambda);

    FindU= intersect((x<=u),(u<=y));
    P_empirical(i)=sum(FindU)./ length(u);
end
```

but of course this kind of implementation creates $X,Y$ both dependent!

Comment: can you use exprnd ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call exprnd twice or if you want to continue on this path (inverse transform), you need to define two vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$, i.e.

```
%create unifrom vector U belongs to [0,1] containing 1e6 samples.
clear all
clc
u = rand(1e4,1);
u1 = rand(1e4,1); % for X
u2 = rand(1e4,1); % for Y

%create function g(u,lambda) for the RV transformation, X=g(u).
% this g(u) definition garanteed X to be with exponent PDF
g=@(u,lambda) (1./lambda).* log(1./(1-u));

lambdaVEC=0.1:0.1:30;
P_empirical=zeros(1,length(lambdaVEC));
for i=1:length(lambdaVEC)
Currlambda=lambdaVEC(i);

x=g(u1,Currlambda); % use u1 here which is independent from u2
y=g(u2,Currlambda); % use u2 here which is independent from u1

num = sum((x<=u)&(u<=y)); % this is the proper way to count the elements between between x and y
P_empirical(i)=num./ length(u);
end
```